# Open Links via HttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

Please help with HttpHandler

There is a HttpHandler that handles links to mysite.ru.

Registered in Web.Config as follows:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
     <httpHandlers>

       <add verb="*" path="mysite.ru" type="App_Code.SyncHttpHandler"/>

     </httpHandlers>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now through the Handler open only references of the form:

mysite.ru
mysite.ru/struct/
mysite.ru/articles/

How to make the handler to intercept and treatment on the links of the form:

mysite.ru/files/images/img.jpg
mysite.ru/files/scripts/script.js

---

If I write so that you can run any links, including SyncHttpHandler/Google.ru.
And I need to be able to run only links a specific site.

`<add verb="*" path="mysite.ru/*.*" type="App_Code.SyncHttpHandler"/>` don't work

`<add verb="*" path="*.*" type="App_Code.SyncHttpHandler"/>` open any links

Answer (score 0):

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.js" validate="false" type="SyncHttpHandler" />
    <add verb="*" path="*.jpg" validate="false" type="SyncHttpHandler" />
</httpHandlers>
```

you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, IIS process all static files by its own static file handler. So you need to first configure your IIS to pass all files (extensions) under this path to ASP.NET run-time. Exact steps (although similar) will depend upon IIS version - for example, see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/3fd05620-78f1-4d51-8709-b142807cf9de.mspx?mfr=true) for IIS 6.

Next part would be making sure that ASP.NET runtime passes all those requests to your handler. As such, I think that your config should work but if it doesn't then try using wild-cards. For example,

```
 <add verb="*" path="mysite.ru/*.*" type="App_Code.SyncHttpHandler"/>
```

or perhaps,

```
<location path="mysite.ru" >
 <system.web>
   <add verb="*" path="*.*" type="App_Code.SyncHttpHandler"/>
 </system.web>
</location>
```